# How to download a file with particular name via using download attribute?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to download file, which is generated by server in maner as below:

```
public downloadZip(): void{
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute(
      'href',
      `/srv/genZip?id=${this.id}`
    );
    link.setAttribute('download', '123.zip');
    link.click();
  }
```

But it doesn't work... Does anyone have an idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Doesn't download at all? Downloads with a different name? Something else?

Comment: "But it doesn't work" That's hardly a detailed description of the problem and expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *absolutely* drive this process, you can only provide hints to the browser.

The browser has a couple of different places it *may* look for a filename for the download:

- The server's [`Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), which can include a filename, for instance
  `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="123.zip"`
  or
  `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*="123.zip"`
- The [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download)

As far as I can tell, there's no specification saying which should have preference, so to maximize the browsers across which your code will work, I'd specify the same name in both.

Underscoring that, there's this note in MDN's coverage of `Content-Disposition` above:

> **Note:** Chrome, and Firefox 82 and later, prioritize the HTML `<a>` element's `download` attribute over the `Content-Disposition: inline` parameter (for same-origin URLs). Earlier Firefox versions prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

So if your server is returning `Content-Disposition: inline` and you're seeing the resource loaded inline (not downloaded), you may be using an older copy of Firefox or a browser that does the same thing.